# minimize iOS-Phonegap/Cordova App

Tags: ios, cordova

In a Phonegap Javascript app I close the Android Version of this app with `navigator.app.exitApp();`

As we know, closing apps is not allowed in iOS.
But the iPad User can minimize the app into the background e.g. by swiping.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible that I could minimize the app programmatically?
2. Is there an event when the user minimizes the app?

Answer (score 1):

This concerns your point Nr 2: When the App is minimized, i.e. put to the background, the "pause" Event is fired and can be handled. See details in the documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

[UPDATE]: This concerns Nr.1: you could write a phonegap plugin that let's you call another intent, i.e. the Home Screen, which would automatically put your app into background, without terminating it. See also [Pause an Android App with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434845/pause-an-android-app-with-phonegap)