# Secha touch App Exit Button

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am building an IOS App using sencha touch, planning to place an exit button so when a user click on that button the app closed/Minimized. In fact , I don't want to kill my app , I just want to my app disappear after user click the "exit" button.

How can I do it ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of sencha touch(2.3 released a few days ago) and sencha cmd 4.0 you might be able to do this. But i suggest using phonegap to compile your application, with phonegap you can use native functionalities by making a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). You might be able to do it by opening/switching to the homescreen here is a link to a question that might help you [minimize iOS-Phonegap/Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739506/minimize-ios-phonegap-cordova-app)
Good Luck