# Android application not minimizing by pressing back button after signing

Tags: android, cordova, back-button, minimization

I want to minimize the application by pressing back and home button. so i have used the following code.

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(setIntent);
     }
```

It is working fine in simulator and device before signing the application. But after signing, the application closes by pressing back button.
I have also tried the following code.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
        {
             if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
             {
                this.moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
             }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

But the result is same. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: the back button operation is automatic by the system. Delete all this code from your application that will work as it should.

Comment: Actually this is an PhoneGap application and with out using the above code the back button closes the application.

Comment: I've added the phone gap tag on your post then.

Comment: I still would not recommend start the Launcher activity from the onBackPressed(). Instead finish your activity and let the Android system goes back to whatever it had before on the its stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause an Android App with Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434845/pause-an-android-app-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate, pressing the back button in Android is designed to exit out of the application.  If you press back enough, to remove each of your Activities, the app will close.

I would not suggest over-riding this functionality (regardless of if this a phone gap application).

Comment: the phonegap is running inside a single activity inside a single webview. The webview changes it http-code and the programmer must override the backButton to make the http-code go back before exiting the application and the general behaviour be coherent with a native app. He might not be doing it correctly, but it must some way or another do it.

Comment: Interesting.  Makes sense that phonegap works this way I guess.  Seems like this breaks the standard Android way of doing things (so the only way to exit the app would be to use the System menu to kill the process - or put an 'exit' button in the app - which is bad).

Comment: The developer have to do it properly, in a way that at the end of the http-code going `back`, it exits the app, just like a native would do. Remembering that the Home button remains there if the user wants to just pause stuff.

Comment: @Budius that is the way a PhoneGap app works by default. Over-riding onBackPressed like this is a bad idea.

Comment: The actual problem is the the code is working fine before signing the application but not working after signing.