# How can I immediately pause execution of a native Angular app?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I'm working with Cordova 3.5 on Android for my Angular app. I need to pause my application so I can debug at the very beginning of the apps execution.

If I use a breakpoint or debugger line in the code the problem is I can't open the chrome developer tools fast enough for to catch the breakpoint to halt execution. If you close the app and relaunch it you have to open a new inspector window.

Any ideas on how to pause the app so I have enough time to open the developer tools?

Comment: You can use the answer [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434845/pause-an-android-app-with-phonegap?rq=1).

Comment: There is `debugger;` but I don't know if it will work in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the rep to comment, but maybe try

```
alert(1);
debugger;
```

...fire up the inspector then OK the alert?

If it crashes out when trying to alert() you might want to try the [Cordova notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) plugin, but the last reference to that I can find in the Cordova docs is for version 3.3.